# New eagle library: reuse standard package & symbol

Tags: eaglecad

I need to make few components in Eagle, which are all in standard packages, and I can see them in ref-packages.lbr.

The problem is that when I am creating my library I don't see how I can reuse package/symbol from another library, so that I only need to give new names to the pins and that's it? Package list is just empty and I can only draw one from scratch.

Unfortunately, all tutorials I've found in the internets do everything from scratch...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can just copy a package from another library into your own library and edit it. 
Are you asking how to copy between libraries?

1. Open your own library (the one you
   want to copy to).
2. Then bring the Control Panel window
   to the front (leaving your library
   open in the background).
3. In the list to the left, expand
   Libraries and expand the name of the
   library you want to copy from.
4. Locate the package or footprint you
   want to copy, right click it, and
   select Copy to Library.
5. Bring the window with your own
   library to the front, locate the
   newly copied package and edit it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking - it works  :-) I was expecting that there is a way to use standard packages without copying all of them to my library...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the version of Eagle that is baked into Fusion360, you'll find there isn't an equivalent of the "Control Panel" or "Table of Contents" as mentioned in the other answers. Starting from your own library:

1. Click the toolbar icon for Add Component/Symbol/Footprint/Package
2. Click the "Import..." button on the device name dialog
3. Navigate the libraries and locate the item you wish to copy
4. Select the item and click OK to drop a clone into your library

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is open your Library, then go to **Library>Table of Contents**.

From there you right click what you want to copy and select copy and save it with a new name.